# Is .Alp file enough to run model on other device

Tags: file, anylogic

I'm currently not having the option to check this question since I do not have 2 computers running Anylogic.

My question is if you share your anylogic .Alp file with somebody, is he able to open the model.

Or should you also need to share the things in your model file when you save it(3d map, databasemap and pictures)

Or do you even need more since when you save an anylogic file you also need to name the Java package.

I'm asking this because my computer is running on his end and I need to know what I've to put in the cloud when my computer will crash and will not be able to use it.

Im currently have put the map from the model map in the cloud and the database excel files. (But no file about the Java package cause I could not find it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the `.alp` file itself and all items that are in the model folder where the `.alp` sits. This can include:

- images
- database subfolder
- lib subfolder (holding any required jar files)
- logs subfolder
- outputs subfolder

So if you simply zip the entire model folder and send it over, the other person unzips it AND IF he/she uses the same AnyLogic version, all will work.

If it is an older version of AnyLogic on the other end, it may not work (but also it may, it depends on the version difference).

Also, if you created the model with the Professional version and you used some elements that are not accessible in the free PLE version and if the other person only uses the PLE, it will also not work.

If you really just need the other person to run the model, consider compiling it or using the AnyLogic cloud.